# Simulating Time Series Model in R

Tags: time-series, simulation, alpha, arima, beta

I want to answer the following question, I know that I can use the arima.sim function but I am not sure how to simulate model asked:

I want to simulate the following:

yt =α+βt+φyt−1 +εt, εt ∼IIDN(0,1)

when: alpha=1, beta=0 and theta=0.8

Before each simulation we should set the seed to 100,000. Assume a starting value of y0=0 and obtain 500 observations. I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
set.seed(seed = 100000)
e <- rnorm(500)
m1 <- arima.sim(model = list(c(ma=0.8,alpha=1,beta=0)),n=500)
```

I have to simulate 4 different models for 4 different values of beta, theta and alpha. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `beta = 0` then there is no (deterministic) time-dependent trend. Are you sure this is correct? In that case you have a simple MA(1) process with a non-zero mean. PS. You seem to be mixing up phi and theta. Your equation contains phi (for the MA(1) component), but later you write `theta = 0.8`. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. (α,β,φ) = (1,0,0.8)

```
set.seed(seed = 1232020)
e <- rnorm(500,mean=0,sd=1)

alpha <- 1
beta <- 0
theta <- 0.8
m_1 <- 0
for(i in 2:length(e)){
  m_1[i] <- alpha+beta*i+theta*m_1[i-1]+e[i]
}
```

Think this should do the trick :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you were using `arima.sim` in your attempt, here is an `arima.sim` option:

```r
set.seed(100000)
t <- 1:500
alpha <- 1
beta <- 0
theta <- 0.8
ts <- alpha + beta * t + arima.sim(list(ma = theta), n = length(t))
```

Since `beta = 0`, there is no deterministic time-dependent trend, and the process corresponds to an MA(1) process with non-zero mean `alpha`.

This decomposition into a deterministic and stochastic term corresponds to rewriting your equation as

[image]

with the MA(1) process

[image]

where the ϵ's are the i.i.d. N(0, 1) residuals.

We can visualise the data

```r
library(forecast)
autoplot(ts)
```

[image]